# Is 'resting stably' right?

Tags: verbs

This part is designed for resting stable on the curved surface

Is 'resting stable' right?

Comment: 'Rest' usually connotes (at least) a sentient actor, an agent. I rest the device on the table; the device stands on the table. 'Stand' can take an adverb or a linked adjective, though some combinations are more idiomatic than others, and some are more common when used metaphorically ('We stand secure against the attacks ...').

Answer (score 1):

To me, the complicating aspect of the sentence "This part is designed for resting stable on the curved surface" is that I can't tell whether the part is designed in such a way as to rest stably itself on the curved surface (by including a complementary curve in it design, for example), or whether it is designed in such a way as to allow a second (or third) object to rest stably on the curved surface (by attaching as a kind of fencing along the sides of the curved surface, for example).

In other words, the sentence as written might mean

> This part is designed for resting itself stably on the curved surface.

or

> This part is designed for resting other objects stably on the curved surface.

If the former meaning is the one you want, I would reword the sentence as follows:

> This part is designed to rest stably on the curved surface.

If the latter is what you have in mind, I would use this wording:

> This part is designed to allow you to rest objects stably on the curved surface.

In any of these cases, I would use *stably* (an adverb) in preference to *stable* (an adjective) unless I reorganized the sentence to allow *stable* to function as an adjective—as, for example, here:

> This part is designed to be stable when placed on the curved surface.